# Ejabberd Message Acknowledgment from Server

Tags: ejabberd

I have setup and implemented ejabberd server with my little mobile app chatting program. Have implemented XEP-184 for the message delivery status as well.

But I am having an issue, how would it possible for my app to know if my message has indeed reached the ejabberd server?

My scenario: I am walking into a weak connection signal area, the signal is barely strong enough to keep the connection alive, but with frequent timeout. I tried to send a message out, how would it possible that I can confirm if the message reaches the server?

Hope I am clear enough on my question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this issue .. I'll be glad to know if there is any ... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an ejabberd mod for this which you can find at:

https://github.com/kmtsar/ejabberd-mods

Comment: I am going to try the mod, is it fine for me to message you if I run into any issue applying the mod? Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah, sure, although I do not work on it anymore, but have seen other people on Github helping out.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach would be to implement [XEP-0198 Stream Management](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0198.html). Stream management is a standard feature in latest ejabberd versions.

With that in place, a client can ask the server to keep a count of the received stanzas, and when interested ask the server to confirm the number of received stanzas.

The client can then get an idea whether one or more stanza were received or not.

This can be done for every single stanza: the client requires an ack for the last sent stanza, and expects an ACK from the server.

In theory you could implement just the "Basic Ack Scenarios" - no need for the full XEP (which includes stream resumption).